# Maintain a persistent Serial connection that dajaxice calls can use?

Tags: python, django, dajaxice

I have a basic django setup running and am currently implementing dajaxice calls to write some data to the serial connection (a RainbowDuino is on the other end).

The following code works however when you establish a serial connection to the Arduino you must wait before writing data to it as the Arduino resets.

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
import time, serial

def serialWrite(msg):
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
        time.sleep(1.5) #wait for arduino to reset
        ser.write(msg)
        return "Running Animation"
    except:
        return "Failed to communicate with cube"

@dajaxice_register
def animate(request, data):
    msg = serialWrite(str(data))
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':msg})
```

I'm new to all things python and django so I'm unsure how to maintain a persistent object that could use the serial connection in this environment. From my own reading and testing I can see that the dajaxice registered method is only called on receipt of the corresponding button click.

Is this a case where I could potentially use my app's view to instantiate a serial connection, if so how could I share the connection with a dajaxice call?

Comment: It might not be an ideal setup, but do you have a specific reason to set up a persistent connection? There might be other ways, but they really depend on your runtime setup (how you are actually serving your Django app). A different approach could be to run a separate process which sets up a persistent connection with your Arduino and listens for commands sent from Django (perhaps via Redis).

Comment: Honestly it's just a personal preference, it doesn't look great when the 4x4 led cube just switches off when resetting. Currently the django app is being served from a raspberry pi, it's a requirement of a school project. I'll investigate Redis, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A middleware might be an option if your runtime environment is simple.

```
// middleware/__init__.py
class ArduinoMiddleware:

    def __init__(self):
        self.serial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
        time.sleep(1.5)

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.serialWrite = self.serialWrite

    def serialWrite(self, msg):
        try:
            self.serial.write(msg)
            return "Running Animation"
        except:
            return "Failed to communicate with cube"

// ajax.py
@dajaxice_register
def animate(request, data):
    msg = request.serialWrite(str(data))
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':msg})

// settings.py
...
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'middleware.ArduinoMiddleware',
  ...
)
```

Untested, and might require locking if you're running in a multithreaded environment (like `manage.py runserver`).

Comment: Thanks, that looks to work just right. I'll be sure to accept once I get to test it with the Arduino tomorrow.